# Typescript: Date changes a dropdown menu

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a menu where initially the user has to select a date. And then select an option from a following dropdown menu.

The values in this dropdown menu are obtained from the database where I have created an API call for and this is working.
However, the options do change based on the date selected.  My issue is, I can't seem to figure out a way to call the API('getOptions' -> to get the list of values) once a user has selected a date.

Any help would be appreciated. Code is below. Many Thanks

**HTML**

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p class="word">Date:</p> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" [(ngModel)]=selectedDate>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p class="word">Options:</p> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select name="Template" class="form-control">
                        <option>- -Select Template- -</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let x of optionsAvailable">{{ x.Value }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**TS**

```
  selectedDate = '';
  optionsAvailable: any = {};

  constructor(
    private commonService: CommonService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getOptions() {
    this.commonService.getOptions(this.selectedDate).subscribe(
      data =>  {
        this.optionsAvailable= [];
        for (let x = 0; x < data['data'].length; x++) {
          this.optionsAvailable.push({
            Id: data['data'][x][0],
            Value: data['data'][x][1]
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the needed time to see if this solution actually builds, but it should be enough to understand the idea behind it:

```
this.form.get("date").valueChanges
.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.commonService.getOptions(this.selectedDate))
)
.subscribe(data =>  {
    this.optionsAvailable= [];

    for (let x = 0; x < data['data'].length; x++) {
      this.optionsAvailable.push({
        Id: data['data'][x][0],
        Value: data['data'][x][1]
      });
    }
 });
```

Bottom line, using `valueChanges` on your date selector, the resulted observable will emit a value on every date selection which will make the `switchMap` bring the data from the backend for it.

Again, the solution is not tested but this is roughly how you could solve this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Should this be in by getOptions() function? I am not entirely understanding how this connects to my date selector.

Comment: no, this should / could be in ngOnInit